# displaying related content in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, content

I am trying to display related content on a custom object within a Visualforce page. I created a custom object and attached a content document to it. I tried doing it using just Visualforce with the `<apex:relatedList list="contentDistribution"`> tag (as well as some other relatedList options). That does not work. I tried a custom controller extension like so:

```
public class GVFExtension{
public List<ContentDocumentLink> gvfcontent;
public global_views__c gvfrecord;

public GVFExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    this.gvfRecord=(Global_Views__c)stdController.getRecord();
}

public List<ContentDocumentLink> getGVFContent(){

gvfContent=[SELECT ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.title
            FROM ContentDocumentLink
            WHERE LinkedEntityId=:gvfRecord.Id];
return gvfContent;
}
```

}

And then my VF page (at least the relevant part):

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Related Content">
          <apex:PageblockTable value="{!GVFContent}" var="g">
                <apex:column>
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!g.id}" target="_blank">{!g.ContentDocumentTitle}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!g.ContentDocumentId}"/>
            </apex:PageblockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
```

The header for the page block appears, but no related content appears (although I confirm it does appear on standard page layouts). When I look at my debug log it says that the extension was invoked properly but that the relatedRecordId query is using tmpVar1.  I'm not sure what I am missing here.

If I can do it using a related list tag, that would be preferable, but all my searching indicates this is not so. I am using API version 33.0.

EDIT: Aha! I found that I should be using ContentDocumentLink, according to new Spring '15 options. Details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.194.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm). So I updated my code above. The problem is, I still am not getting anything appearing in the Related Content view. The title appears but there is nothing showing.

Comment: have you tried getting rid of the "rendered ..." tag?  Also, the "header"  column can't display any data, there's no "value" tag there.

Comment: Also, if contentdistribution is a related list then you would want <apex:relatedList list="contentDistribution__r"> (note the "__r").  More here ->http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/05/13/using-related-lists-in-visualforce-pages/

Comment: Even with the __r, does not work. Also took out the render tag. No dice

Comment: Is ContentDistribution a standard object?  I can't see it my my org.

Comment: It's standard if Content is enabled.

Comment: and `gvfContent=[SELECT ContentDocumentId, Name, LastModifiedDate
            FROM ContentDistribution 
            WHERE RelatedRecordId=:gvfRecord.Id]` if executed with anonymous apex returns an empty list?

Comment: If I use the Id of a record that I know has Related Content, yes. So I am unsure as to what object I should be querying (see below for other post I referenced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just discovered some odd and saddening idea exchange posts from Alex sutherland about how this isn't possible...

Worked with mpusto earlier today on this. We determined we'd need to use apex to gather the related content *in apex* and then display. ~30 min of searching has lead to many posts like this one: [How to obtain "Related Content" information in SOQL/APEX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13514/how-to-obtain-related-content-information-in-soql-apex)

Namely that gathering related content from apex isn't possible. Additionally, looking at the ERD (https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content) and then inspecting those objects, I couldn't find a way to relate a given custom object to related content.

Comment: Kevin, perhaps you could add some details or links to the posts you mention for those who might want more? FYI, your post was flagged in the queue.

Comment: Here is the Idea should anyone want to vote on it. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IQvrAAG

Answer (score 1):

One option I've tried (suggested by greenstork privately) was to use `<apex:detail>` with relatedList="true".  This works if I strip out all the unnecessary fields from a page layout, but then I get back to the Salesforce look/feel for the name of the object, which is less than ideal. But surprise! My client actually thought it was ok in this case. So props to greenstork for directing me that way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the correct Child Relationship Name? On your child object, navigate to the lookup field on the child object and look at the Child Relationship Name, that is the value plus __r that you want in your list attribute.

[image]

In this example, the related list tag would be Donations__r

Comment: The related Content seems to be a special case. There is no way for me to look at the child object, as it is the related content. I used the Developer Console to look at the ContentDistribution object, as well as the other Content objects. I was thinking ContentDistribution due to this post: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000AvgRIAS

Comment: Try RelatedRecord or RelatedRecords